# cantor set prove verfication

Tags: solution-verification, cantor-set

**Question**: [image]

**My proof:**[image: First part]
[image: Second Part]

Can anyone help me verify my proof?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Nice handwriting by the way.

Comment: @DavidMitra It looks to me that it is correct - except for the very first line, where it should've said $x\in C$ (rather than $x\in C^c$).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is correct (apart from, as noted in comments, the first line on the $2$nd page should still say $x\in C$ as opposed to $x\in C^c$).

I would probably simplify the first part of the proof by always choosing the "left" end of the subinterval, rather than caring a lot whether to take the left or the right end.

**Commentary**: In essence, if you interpret Cantor set as the real numbers in $[0,1]$ written in the ternary system without using the digit $1$, then, for $x\in C$ you have the ternary expansion such as:

$$x=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}a_na_{n+1}\ldots$$

where $a_i\in\{0,2\}$, and in the first case you can use:

$$x_n=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}a_n$$

(a finite expansion - that is what I am suggesting above), or:

$$x_n=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}a_na_na_n\ldots$$

(which is what you are doing in your original proof). In the second case, you are using

$$x_n=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}111\ldots$$

which is perfectly ok.